# how to regenerate entities in jhipster import-jdl your-jdl-file.jh

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

Is there any way to tell jhipster import-jdl that you want to delete old entities already created and drop the database to create a new structure without creating a new proyect?

When I make changes jhispter keeps my old entities and everyting gets dirty.

Thanks,

Comment: No. There was an attempt to do so but it did not complete, if you want to contribute it would be a good start https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4403

Comment: I wish I can understand a simple app with JHipster. I'm not a programmer, just a wanabe ;-), but thanks. I'm thinking about zipping a fresh project and deleting it when dirty. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: I would rather use git

Comment: Of course! You see, I'm a wannabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There was an attempt to do so but it did not complete, if you want to contribute it would be a good start github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4403 – Gaël Marziou Apr 23 at 23:12

The points should go to Gaël (I want to close this question).

Thanks Gaël Marziou